# Open new tab close first window selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am navigating to a website using selenium VBA and I used `.Get sURL`
After the first iteration of rows, from which I take a number to search. I would like to delete the cookies then open new tab and do the same process but with the new tab ( and at the same time close the first window)
The problem with the website is that it shows alert when opening and that caused a problem for me. I tried to add argument and disable notifications using such a line `bot.AddArgument "--disable-notifications"` but this seems not to work

[image]

I have tried a lot but with no success

```
    .Manage.DeleteAllCookies
    .Wait 1000
    .Manage.DeleteAllCookies
    '.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", ""
    .ExecuteScript "window.open();"
    .Get sURL
     .SwitchToAlert.Accept
     Stop
    .SwitchToNextWindow
    
    .Windows(1).Close
    .Window.Activate
    .SwitchToNextWindow
```

Simply I need to close the first window and open a new tab on which I could do the same process as for the first iteration

This is the whole code for testing

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Const sURL As String = "http://portal.acs.moi.gov.kw/wps/portal/!ut/p/c1/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3jHEEf3EENTIwMLD1dLA88Qv2AzMzM3IwMDU6B8JJK8v3-AmYGRr7G3qYmvhwEQENAdDrIPv36QvAEO4Gig7-eRn5uqH6kfZY7THncz_cic1PTE5Er9gtwIgyyTUEUANhX2ig!!/dl2/d1/L0lJSklna21DU1EhIS9JRGpBQU15QUJFUkNKRXFnL1lGTkExTkk1MC01Rjg5dyEvN19BVEFHVDE1MjA4SEU5MElUTlM2NjZGMjBHNi86bF9fXzQ1LzE5MTU4MzUzNTk!/?"

Sub Demo()
    Dim eleSearch As Selenium.WebElement, m As Long, lr As Long, r As Long, cnt As Long
    lr = shSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    m = shSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With bot
        '.AddArgument "--headless"
        .AddArgument "--disable-notifications"
        .Get sURL
        .SwitchToAlert.Accept
        Dim f As Boolean
        For r = m To lr
            'If r Mod 10 = 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.StatusBar = "Civil ID: " & shSheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value & " ------- Row " & r
            If f = True Then
                .Manage.DeleteAllCookies
                .Wait 1000
                .Manage.DeleteAllCookies
                '.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", ""
                .ExecuteScript "window.open();"
                .Get sURL
                .SwitchToAlert.Accept
                Stop
                .SwitchToNextWindow
            
                .Windows(1).Close
                .Window.Activate
                .SwitchToNextWindow
            End If
            With .FindElementByName("numberValue")
                .Clear: .SendKeys shSheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
            End With
            .FindElementByName("search").Click
            shSheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value = Trim(.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").Text)
            f = True
        Next r
    End With
    Application.StatusBar = Empty
End Sub
```

some numbers to test on `294030604637` `284083101217` `290061002171`

Comment: Doesn't selenium basic have the ability to switch to alert either with explicit function ? `driver.SetCapability "unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "ignore"` ; `Set ele = driver.SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)` and finally `ele.Accept` - to handle the alert. Or is this actually a pop-up to be handled with switching windows?

Comment: I am not sure. I have used `.SwitchToAlert.Accept` and this works for the first iteration but when opening a new tab, it doesn't work. I have posted the whole code so as to test it.

Comment: Did you switch first to the new window

Comment: I tried to switch the new window but the problem is with the alert I think